# Restore lightdm start at boot time

Tags: 16.04, boot, virtualbox, xorg, lightdm

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on Virtualbox. I did install guest additions from the host. While I was troubleshooting a black screen of death, I had set it to boot to console.

Now. I don't remember how can I restore the boot to start `lightdm` automatically. I currently have to run

```
$ sudo service lightdm start
$ sudo killall Xorg
```

on a console before I can actually use it. `lightdm` gives me a black screen on `tty7` until I kill `Xorg`. I have no idea why that happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal means to the set the default run level to boot to GUI is to run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Then do a system `reboot`.